# How to pass a function to React in State to sort your data based on multiple queries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, state, setstate

I am new to React and have a question regarding passing down functions in a state. I have a couple of 'sorting functions' in my util folder, which look like this:

```
export const sortColdestSummerCountries = (filteredCountries) => {
  return filteredCountries.sort(
    (a, b) => a.avsummertemp20802099 - b.avsummertemp20802099
  );
};
```

and a few others:
`sortHighestSummerTemp, sortLargestIncreaseHotDays, sortColdestSummerCountries, sortMostColdDays, sortWorstAffectedCountries` which pretty much look similar. I use them to sort my data by users' request, and if I wrap `sortHighestSummerTemp(filteredCountries)` around my data, it works as a charm.

Now the issue: because I will have eventually 10+ filters, it makes sense to me to create a global state like this:

```
const onChangeQueryFilter = (e) => {
    setQueryFilter(e.target.value);
  };
```

Yet, upon trying  `queryFilter (filteredCountries)` the terminal shows me  `"queryFilter is not a function"` when I filter it? It's still the same  sortHighestSummerTemp function right or what am I missing here? Do I summarize this problem correctly?

Hopefully it was clear and you understand what I am trying to do.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following as well:

```
function sortBy(filteredCountries, sortKey) {
     return [...filteredCountries].sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);   
}

// the queryFilter responds to the key, "filteredCountries.avsummertemp20802099" for example which passes to [sortKey].

const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState(filteredCountries.avsummertemp20802099);
const filteredData = sortBy(filteredCountries, queryFilter);
```

This does not work either, it still shows the old data (filteredCountries) but the filtering doesn't happen, the data isn't sorted. Does someone have a clue what I am doing wrong? Is it something in the sorting method? Or does someone have a better practice to pass a function to state?

Thank you a lot for being out here. :)

Comment: Hi Bridlers, since `queryFilter` is a part of state I think that you could try to "listen" for its changes by using `useEffect`. Try to log `sortBy(filteredCountries, queryFilter)` inside `useEffect`. E.g. `useEffect(() => { ... }, [queryFilter])`

Comment: And what should be inside the { ... } in this scenario?

Comment: Try to console `sortBy(filteredCountries, queryFilter);`

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for helping, really appreciated that people like you are here! 

```function sortBy(filteredCountries, sortKey) {
    return [...filteredCountries].sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);
  }
  const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState(
    filteredCountries.avwintertemp20802099
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    sortBy(filteredCountries, queryFilter);
  }, [queryFilter]) ```

Right now, I am trying this and unfortunately it's not sorting the data. When I ```console.log(filteredCountries); ``` it's also showing me an unsorted list 